# How to test result of Control.Exception.Assert with HSpec

Tags: haskell, hspec

I want to use [Control.Exception.Assert](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/assert-0.0.1.2/docs/Control-Exception-Assert.html) to get custom error messages.

And I want to test these with [HSpec](http://hspec.github.io/).

In the repl I can see:

```
λ: import           Control.Exception
λ: import           Control.Exception.Assert
λ: (byEq assert "Bool" True  True ())
()
λ: (byEq assert "Bool" False True ())
*** Exception: <interactive>:6:7-12: Assertion failed "Bool", False ≠ True
```

How does one test that the exception and message are correct?  In other word, for the case where `byEq` throws an exception I want to test both the exception type and the exception message are what are expected.

Something like:

```
main = hspec $ do
  describe "Assertions" $ do
    it "assert" $ do
      evaluate (byEq assert "Bool" False True ()) `shouldThrow` ????
```

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss about what you want to achieve. In the first place, you've shown the actual output from ghci, but not what output you were hoping for; in the second place, you haven't said what it means for an exception and message to be correct.

Comment: The `assert` package seems to throw exceptions of type `Arse` (aptly named...) so `??? = \(_ :: Arse) -> True` would pass for any error message produced by `byEq`. The second argument to `shouldThrow` is simply a function `e -> Bool` for some `Exception e`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I added a clarification.

Comment: @user2407038 That will test that the exception type is correct, but not that the message is correct.   Plus, I tried it and it gave: `did not get expected exception: Arse`

Comment: Rather than testing that `byEq assert "Bool" x y ()` produces the message `Assertion failed "Bool", False ≠ True`, wouldn't it be more sane to simply have `byEq assert "foo" (x,y) (False,True) ()` as the test?

Comment: @DanielWagner I am not sure what you mean.   For the sake of the example I put the `byeq` directly in the test.  In my "real" code, this would be in some function in the library/application.  I would call that and then want to ensure I do indeed receive the expected exception and the expected message.  I think there is a layer of magic in Control.Exception.Assert I do not understand.